# Error when execute the command ng build --prod (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular6, production

I'm getting an error, when I'm executing the command `ng build --prod` in Angular. I've finished my little project and I need to generate the files to upload to my hosting provider.

**ERROR - ANGULAR CLI**

```
C:\Users\Johan Corrales\Documents\GitHub\inventory>ng build --prod

Date: 2018-07-16T19:15:30.635Z
Hash: 7c51a01b7d98bff3951d
Time: 16720ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.e0a8f821933ac7e59b03.js (scripts) 154 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.fa70ecd2f42fd8700239.css (styles) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.207dcc605630215505f5.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.f58b96bf9bf614ca37d4.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(35,112): : Property 'nombre_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(39,110): : Property 'fecha_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(43,112): : Property 'ciudad_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(51,115): : Property 'direccion_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(55,112): : Property 'numero_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(59,112): : Property 'codigo_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

> Some many variables or properties are in spanish language.

**VIEW / HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group text-left">
       <label class="">Bodega</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Nombre de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.nombre_bodega">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
       <label class="">Fecha de Registro</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Fecha de registro" [value]="listadoBodegas.fecha_bodega" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label class="">Ciudad</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Ciudad de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.ciudad_bodega">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group text-left">
       <label class="">Dirección</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Dirección de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.direccion_bodega">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
       <label class="">Número</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Número de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.numero_bodega">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label class="">Código</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Código de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.codigo_bodega">
    </div>
</div>
```

**TYPESCRIPT / COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
//Importacion de servicios
import { BodegaService } from './../services/bodega.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detalle-bodega',
  templateUrl: './detalle-bodega.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detalle-bodega.component.css']
})
export class DetalleBodegaComponent implements OnInit {

  //Declaracion del array para el listado de las bodegas
  listadoBodegas:any[] = [];
  //Declaracion de modelos
  nombre_bodega:any;
  fecha_bodega:any;
  ciudad_bodega:any;
  direccion_bodega:any;
  numero_bodega:any;
  codigo_bodega:any;

  constructor(
    private ruta:ActivatedRoute,
    private _service:BodegaService
  ){
    this.ruta.params.subscribe(params=>{
      //console.log("params: " , params['id']);
      this.listadoBodegas = this._service.obtenerIndexBodega(params['id']);
      //console.log("listado: ", this.listadoBodegas)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**TYPESCRIPT / SERVICE.TS**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BodegaService {

  //Declaracion de modelos
  nombre_bodega:any;
  fecha_bodega:any;
  ciudad_bodega:any;
  direccion_bodega:any;
  numero_bodega:any;
  codigo_bodega:any;

  //Declaracion de array
  listadoBodegas:any[] = [
    {
      nombre_bodega:'Mac Pollo',
      numero_bodega:'200',
      ciudad_bodega:'Pereira, Risaralda',
      direccion_bodega: 'Via el pollo',
      codigo_bodega:'1000',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    },
    {
      nombre_bodega:'Corosito',
      numero_bodega:'201',
      ciudad_bodega:'Pereira, Risaralda',
      direccion_bodega: 'Via el pollo',
      codigo_bodega:'1001',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    },
    {
      nombre_bodega:'INCAUCA',
      numero_bodega:'202',
      ciudad_bodega:'Cali, Valle del Cauca',
      direccion_bodega: 'Centro logístico',
      codigo_bodega:'1002',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    },
    {
      nombre_bodega:'El Bombillo',
      numero_bodega:'203',
      ciudad_bodega:'La Virginia, Risaralda',
      direccion_bodega: 'Zona Franca',
      codigo_bodega:'1003',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    },
    {
      nombre_bodega:'El Arriero',
      numero_bodega:'204',
      ciudad_bodega:'Pereira, Risaralda',
      direccion_bodega: 'Cerritos',
      codigo_bodega:'1004',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    }
  ]

  constructor() { }

  consultarBodega()
  {
    return this.listadoBodegas;
  }

  obtenerIndexBodega(id)
  {
    return this.listadoBodegas[id];
  }
}
```

I have to say that when is running with the command `ng serve` in angular cli, all is running in a correct way. So, what I'm doing wrong? angular cli shows that error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng build --prod is making a smaller bundle size than just ng build or ng serve. So because of that all the type definitions are strictly checked.

You just need to get rid of all the errors and the build will go through.

As we can see from the error that is outputed. You have a problem with

```
listadoBodegas: any[] = [];
```

just make it any:

```
listadoBodegas: any = [];
```

or

```
listadoBodegas: Array<any> = [];
```

And as we can see you have an array of objects, so you would need to iterate thorugh the array like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listadoBodegas">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group text-left">
            <label class="">Bodega</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Nombre de la bodega" [value]="item.nombre_bodega">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-left">
            <label class="">Fecha de Registro</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Fecha de registro" [value]="item.fecha_bodega" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-left">
            <label class="">Ciudad</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Ciudad de la bodega" [value]="item.ciudad_bodega">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group text-left">
            <label class="">Dirección</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Dirección de la bodega" [value]="item.direccion_bodega">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-left">
            <label class="">Número</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Número de la bodega" [value]="item.numero_bodega">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-left">
            <label class="">Código</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Código de la bodega" [value]="item.codigo_bodega">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

or maybe just ouput the first index of an array:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label class="">Bodega</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Nombre de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas[0].nombre_bodega">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label class="">Fecha de Registro</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Fecha de registro" [value]="istadoBodegas[0].fecha_bodega" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label class="">Ciudad</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Ciudad de la bodega" [value]="istadoBodegas[0].ciudad_bodega">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label class="">Dirección</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Dirección de la bodega" [value]="istadoBodegas[0].direccion_bodega">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label class="">Número</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Número de la bodega" [value]="istadoBodegas[0].numero_bodega">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label class="">Código</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Código de la bodega" [value]="istadoBodegas[0].codigo_bodega">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Understood, but, I've forgotten say that this piece of my code is an page as "Master - Detail" so, I have a bodegas (warehouse) list, and one option that you can watch all the details of that warehouse, so I need to show the detail of everyone in an input with type text.. For that way I'm not using a loop (ngFor).

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
  obtenerIndexBodega(id)
  {
    return this.listadoBodegas[id];
  }
```

Is returning *one* element (object) from the array, not an array.

So this:

```
listadoBodegas:any[] = [];
```

Needs to be this:

```
listadoBodegas = {};
```

Also, I would recommend defining an interface for your listadoBodegas so you don't need to use the 'any' data type.

Comment: Hi @DeborahK I've forgotten say that this type of page has an other page as "Master - Detail". For that I'm using that part of the code. So, the warehouse list as first page, if I touch the button "details" it takes me a new interface for show every details from the warehouse selected.

Comment: Then your "master" page is missing the *ngFor to loop through the items to display in the list. I have a complete example of a master/detail page here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Final Check out the products folder for the product list and product detail pages. Hopefully those will help.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have listadoBodegas, an array of anything.

```
listadoBodegas : any[]
```

and you write:

```
listadoBodegas.nombre_bodega
```

**This is not possible**. You have a **List [] OR and object** with the attribute nombre_bodega but not both of them.

So maybe, you dont have an array and remove the **[]** from your type. Or if it's an array, you need to get the different elements inside.

Comment: so, whats the correct way to show data in a type page "master - detail", Because the page bodegas has the list of bodegas and you touch the button Details and the next component is the detail of that bodega (warehouse)

Comment: @DeborahK and other members have given also good answer. You can check them

Answer (score -1):

When you serve your application some errors that doesn't break the application might not be shown.
You are binding value of you inputs to an empty array.
You can do this to avoid this problem

`<input type="text"
 [value]="listadoBodegas.nombre_bodega?">`

Adding `?` after a value in a binding will check if the value exist or not.

Comment: Firstly, it would be `listadoBodegas?.nombre_bodega`, and secondly, that isn't the issue here. That would cause a runtime error, and OP is asking about a compile time error.

Comment: The error here is that listaBodegas is an empty array, so accessing listaBodegas.nombre_bodega would cause an error because nombre_bodega doesn't exist in listadoBodega.

Comment: Nope, the error is a compile time error. The compiler has no idea that the array is empty. The real problem is because an array does not have a `nombre_bodega` property. Also, as @DeborahK has pointed out, `obtenerIndexBodega` doesn't even return an array, so shouldn't be typed as such

Comment: And why it run with Ng serve?

Comment: Because `ng build --prod` (unlike `ng serve`) performs AOT compilation, so it will try to spot any errors in the template as well

Comment: I don't understand why this work while serving? This should give an error when the component is loaded, because he is binding to an undefined vale anyway, sorry just trying to understand this because I've got the same error and I resolved this way.

Comment: `listadoBodegas` is never undefined, it's initialised to an empty array within the component, and then replaced with the correct object when the service returns from `obtenerIndexBodega`